# R: cut function with breaks for every two months

Tags: r

I've learnt from somewhere that for `Date` vector we can use `cut` to split into bins:

```
cut(dates, breaks='quarter')
```

Now I want to change it so that it breaks by every two months, how can I do that?

I try to look it up by `?cut`, but it won't even show that I can use `'quarter'` or `'month'` to break. Where can I find a more detailed document about this usage?

```
breaks: 
either a numeric vector of two or more unique cut points or a single number (greater than or equal to 2) giving the number of intervals into which x is to be cut.
```

Comment: Go to `?cut.POSIXt` for information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bit of an unfortunate side-effect of S3 classes: you need to make sure you're looking at the appropriate help. Don't look at `?cut`, look at `?cut.Date` or `?cut.POSIXt` (as BondedDust suggests).

From that help:

> `breaks`   a vector of cut points or number giving the number of intervals which x is to be cut into or an interval specification, one of "sec", "min", "hour", "day", "DSTday", "week", "month", "quarter" or "year", optionally preceded by an integer and a space, or followed by "s". For "Date" objects only "day", "week", "month", "quarter" and "year" are allowed.

As @akrun says, for your case you can use `cut(dates, breaks='2 months')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
cut(dates, breaks='2 month')
```