# Clustering dates into buckets of 30 days

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 5 columns. One of these columns contain dates  which I want to cluster for further analysis.

I want to create a new column that generates a number so that:

- Anything within the last 30 day daterange gets a "1"
- Anything within the last 30 to 60 days daterange gets a "2", and so on...

The dates are in a format

```
%Y-%m-%d
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: In general, you can do something like this with `cut`. Look at `cut.Date` for how this applies to dates

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/27280065/5325862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- 
  sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 12)

df %>% 
  enframe(name = NULL) %>% 
  mutate(
    target_date = as.Date('2000/01/01'),
    date_diff = as.numeric(target_date - value),
    what_you_want = ceiling(date_diff / 30)
  )

# A tibble: 12 x 4
   value      target_date date_diff what_you_want
   <date>     <date>          <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 1999-08-02 2000-01-01        152             6
 2 1999-04-09 2000-01-01        267             9
 3 1999-03-05 2000-01-01        302            11
 4 1999-07-06 2000-01-01        179             6
 5 1999-06-12 2000-01-01        203             7
 6 1999-11-14 2000-01-01         48             2
 7 1999-04-03 2000-01-01        273            10
 8 1999-07-27 2000-01-01        158             6
 9 1999-08-12 2000-01-01        142             5
10 1999-03-06 2000-01-01        301            11
11 1999-12-11 2000-01-01         21             1
12 1999-06-15 2000-01-01        200             7
```